# Android App (Lego Speedorz) will not run in restricted profile, crashes instantly

Tags: applications, crashes, restricted-profiles

I have two little kids and for obvious reasons I'm not to keen to let them use my account. Since I have Android 4.4.2 on my Nexus 7 I set up a limited profile today and enabled the kids games for the profile.

Sadly one App (Lego Speedorz) keeps crashing instantly when started. Since there is close to nothing one can setup for apps in restricted profiles I'm at a loss here :-(

Any hint what I could try to get the game running?

Comment: Complain to the app developer. It's up to them to debug and fix the problem. It would be helpful if you report any answer they give back here, so future visitors who find your question know what's going on.

Comment: Seems like the LEGO email system is shut down till december 24th...

Comment: If [this game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wb.speedorz) is the one you're talking about, the developer is Warner Bros Games: their email address is on that page. Lego's nothing to do with the game, they just licensed their trademarks for it.

Comment: I found that out by myself, sorry for not writing it here. I already contacted the support but all I got was "Could you please try the game in a non-restricted profile to see if it crashes? If it does, please delete the game and then re-download it again." I answered that it does work on normal profiles... reply pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After restarting the tablet the app is now working properly. No idea - could be android was not able to free enough RAM or some such...